# junit4 with Netbeans "No tests executed"

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, junit4

I try to use JUnit 4.10 in Netbeans 7.3 for an existing project.

First, I used Netbeans wizard to generate a simple test class on an existing class. Then, I added a simple unit test method as follows :

```
public class UserTest
{

    @Test
    public void deleteAdmin()
    {
        System.out.println("*UserTest: deleteAdmin()");
        failed("failed");
    }
}
```

However, when I made a right-click on file and choose "Test File" in context menu, output console writes :

```
ant -f E:\\Antonin\\Workspace\\Project -Dignore.failing.tests=true -Djavac.includes=package_name/UserTest.java -Dtest.includes=package_name/UserTest.java -DforceRedeploy=false -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true test-single
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-test-single:
No tests executed.
test-single:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I found several Netbeans bug reports on this kind of issue and tried some code variant but sadly I haven't yet resolved the problem.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ? Is it an Ant config related problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally, one of my colleagues has solved my problem.
There was errors in my "project.properties" and "project.xml" files.

Comment: What were these errors?

Comment: Since you are using an annotation, I'd check to make sure you included the correct annotation. TestNG and Junit both have their own annotations and if your dependency lists TestNG but not JUnit, the test will not run. At least that's what happened to me.